# Angular 2 + Jasmine Unit Test - Getting Error TS2345

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular

I followed the unit testing from this website (author: Torgeir Helgevold) @:TGH http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-unit-testing to do unit testing, but got an error:

"Error:(15, 39) TS2345: Argument of type 'FunctionWithParamTokens' is not assignable to parameter of type '(done: () => void) => void'."

```
it('should define full name2', inject([DisplayName], (displayName) => {
            displayName.firstName = 'Joe';
            displayName.lastName = 'Smith';
            displayName.generateFullName();
            expect(displayName.fullName).toBe('Joe Smith');
        }));
```

Is the code in this website out of date? Can anyone give me some reference to learn unit testing with Anuglar2 + Jasmine?

Answer (score 16):

I encountered this error too. The problem was that I was not importing `beforeEach` from `angular2/testing`.

```
import {it, describe, expect, inject, beforeEach} from 'angular2/testing';

describe('Thing', () => {
  let thing: Thing;

  beforeEach(inject([Thing], (t: Thing) => {
    thing = t;
  }));

  it('should do something', () => {
    expect(thing.doSomething()).toBe('I did a thing');
  });
});
```

Comment: This was exactly the cause for my issue too, (well, apart from the original copy and paste from another UT!). Thanks for posting.

Comment: For the record, your import statement fixes the problem, but it isn't `beforeEach` that needs to be imported (which wouldn't make any sense), it's `it` - you need to use Angular's patched `it` function rather than Jasmine's, which is what you're using unless you `import {it} from "angular2/testing"`