# Inject won't work with Jasmine tests for Angular2 (the promise isn't floating up)

Tags: angular, jasmine

So I've got a bit of code I am trying to test using a spec.

```
import {beforeEachProviders, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {TestComponentBuilder} from '@angular/compiler/testing';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
    it('should fail', inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        expect(1).toBe(2);
    }));
});
```

This results in the error:
No provider for TestComponentBuilder!

I have some sanity check tests below and they work:

```
it('true is true', () => expect(true).toEqual(true));
it('null is not the same thing as undefined',
      () => expect(null).not.toEqual(undefined)
    );
```

In PyCharm I am getting an error with inject, it is telling me:
Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(done: DoneFn) => void'. Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(done: DoneFn): void'.

Any help is appreciated, I anticipate I am using some old implementation of inject but I cant find new documentation :)

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error with a beforeEach() statement. You need to import "it" from `@angular/core/testing`. The basic function of Jasmine cannot receive the return of inject().

```
import {beforeEachProviders, inject, it} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

The above should be enough.

I found the solution in that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35589775/2683681

Comment: That solves one of my issues, but I still have am having the issue where it tells me I have no provider for the TestComponentBuilder.

    `Error: No provider for TestComponentBuilder!`

Comment: This is because you have to use `beforeEachProviders` as in this [link](https://gist.github.com/gsans/b30f6c9ddb7d6503ea23#file-greeter-spec-js). Taken from this [good medium article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-unit-testing-with-jasmine-defe20421584#.8pcj1qdex)